# Type definitions in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming

I have a Scala pre-examination question which I cannot get through. Probably someone could help.

Does the expression on the right conforms to the declared type, and why?

(a) `val x1: B => D = (b: A) => new D`

(b) `val x2: A => C => D = (a: A) => (b: D) => new C`

(c) `val x3: (D => B) => A = (db: D => A) => new B`

The class hierarchy:

class A

class B extends A

class C

class D extends C

Comment: I'm assuming `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` have some sort of inheritance structure. In which case, there is not enough information to solve this problem.

Comment: Assuming no particular inheritance structure, then none of them conform. x1 is A => D, x2 is A => D => C, and x3 is (D => A) => B (you should easily see why)

Comment: Thanks for response. Sure, I forgot to put the class hierarchy.  class A;  class B extends A; class C and class D extends A

Answer (score 1):

You don't need us for this. Just paste the code into the REPL.

```
scala> class A
defined class A

scala> class B extends A
defined class B

scala> class C
defined class C

scala> class D extends C
defined class D

scala> val x1: B => D = (b: A) => new D
x1: B => D = <function1>

scala> val x2: A => C => D = (a: A) => (b: D) => new C
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : C
 required: D
       val x2: A => C => D = (a: A) => (b: D) => new C
                                                 ^

scala> val x3: (D => B) => A = (db: D => A) => new B
x3: (D => B) => A = <function1>
```

Comment: Think the question was: how compiler derives types (function subtyping explanation); will try to answer little bit later, if nobody answers.

Comment: Yes, just to explain the "syntactic sugar". Much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that there is no correct expression amongst them.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I just didn't see the class hierarchy before.

Answer (score 0):

Mb there is an answer, which has more information then needed.

- when we write `T => F` -- it means a function type, sugar for a `trait Function1[-P, +R] { def apply(p: P): R }`
- when we write `(t: T) => new F` it means a lambda function, which has a type `T => F`, or (alias, sugar) `Function1[T, F]`, as you can notice `t` is an application argument.
- we have relations on types, one of them is sub typing, so you need an explanation of function sub typing in this task.

Let's consider why code, provided here by @ChrisMartin, compiling.

So function, is a trait:

```
trait Function1[-P, +R] {
  def apply(p: P): R
}
```

That means that function is contravariant (`+`) by argument and covariant (`-`) by result.

Let `F: P → R, p ∈ P => F(p) ∈ R`, and let `F' : P' → R' : P' ⊃ P, R' ⊂ R'`. Then, `p ∈ P => p ∈ P' => F'(p) ∈ R'=> F'(p) ∈ R`.

That means that `F'` function is a special case of `F` function on its domain. In other words some function from a super type of `P` to the sub type of `R` is a subtype of function from `P` to `R`.

In your examples:

- `B => D` is a more general function then `A => D` (`A` is a super type of `B`) (check: `implicitly[(A => D) <:< (B => D)]`)
- `A => C => D` is a more specific function then `A => D => C` (check: `implicitly[(A => C => D) <:< (A => D => C)]`)
- `(D => B) => A` is a more general function then `(D => A) => B` (check: `implicitly[((D => A) => B) <:< ((D => B) => A)]`)